# Unable to define params variables in Serverless console

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework

According to the Serverless [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/parameters#), I should be able to define params within the dashboard/console. But when I navigate there, the inputs are disabled:
[image]

I've tried following the [instructions](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/parameters#cli-parameters) to update via CLI, with: `serverless deploy --param="domain=myapp.com" --param="key=value"`. The deploy runs successfully (I get a `✔ Service deployed to...` message with no errors), but nothing appears in my dashboard. Likewise, when I run a command to check whether there are any params stored: `serverless param list`, I get

```
Running "serverless" from node_modules
No parameters stored
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing `param` flags will not upload the parameters to Dashboard/Console, it will only expose them in your configuration so you can access them with `${param:<param-name>}`. To my best knowledge, it is not possible to set Dashboard parameters with CLI, you need to set them manually via UI.

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions problem. The owner of the account updated the permissions and I was able to update the inputs.